# PyQt5 для Raspberry pi

Tags: python, pyqt5, raspberry-pi

Есть программа написанная на python + PyQt5. Запущена на Raspberry pi. Вопрос, как убрать рамку возле внутри кнопки? Рамка появляется после нажатия. Если после этого нажать другую кнопку, то рамка пропадет и появится на той которая была нажата последней. Пример работы на винде и на распберри. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста пример кода, демонстрирующий показанное вами окно приложения.

Comment: @S.Nick Вот код этого приложения. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I9DfUkHU_j29IU-lPoLzxqYyj709e5SZ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте:

```
StyleSheet = """

QPushButton#FuncBatton {
    text-align:center; 
    border-radius: 16px; 
    border:0px solid #875ba6; 
    font:21px LazyType beta; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    color:#1c2241; 
    background:#d5b9ea; 
}    

QPushButton#FuncBatton:hover{
    border:5px solid #72398a; 
    border-radius: 16px; 
    font:21px LazyType beta; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    color:#875ba6; 
    background:#d5b9ea; 
}

QPushButton#FuncBatton:pressed {
    text-align:center; 
    border-radius: 16px; 
    border:5px solid #875ba6; 
    font:21px LazyType beta; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    color:#1c2241; 
    background:#d5b9ea;
}

QLabel#clock{
    font:30px LazyType beta; 
    color:#875ba6; 
}
"""
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нет, не работает так( Рамка осталась. На винде её нет, а на расбери  есть

Comment: @ДаниилРассадкин опишите, что именно не так работает.

Comment: Я же говорю рамка осталась. Я не хочу чтобы приложение было с полупрозрачными рамками на кнопках. В конце концов оно пишется для расбери, а не для винды